# Python virtualenv date different from OS

Tags: python, virtualenv, robotframework

I am using python `virtualenv` to run robot framework in `linux`.
My doubt is about the system date for `virtualenv`, is it possible to change the date of `virtualenv` **without** changing the OS level system date.

Comment: A virtualenv is literally nothing but a collection of libraries. It's not a "virtual machine" in any kind of sense that would give it an independent clock.

Comment: ...now, there are things you can do to feed invalid results to C library calls checking time from *any* program, and they'll work for the Python interpreter just as well, but that's much more generic functionality, not anything that's in any way Python- or virtualenv-specific (so it would be more appropriate to document it under a general question about "how can I feed my program an invalid time?" or such).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. What I am trying is to create tests in robotframwork that run at a specific time as my test data is.

Comment: Is "robotframework" the thing that's retrieving the current time? Your code? Something else? Mock or monkeypatch whatever's actually doing the check.

Comment: Try googling for `site:stackoverflow.com mock python time` to get some ideas about how other folks have addressed this.

Comment: If you want to fake the system time for some reason, you probably want to check out [time-machine](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/06/03/introducing-time-machine/).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the date in a virtualenv separate from the system time. A virtualenv is nothing more than environment variables and symbolic links to some folders, it is not an isolated system.